# redux persist not storing store in the async storage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

**Note**- If you want to summarize my question, then I would say that I have 5 reducers. Only 2 of them are being persisted while 3 are not.

My `redux-persist` version is 6.0.0. Now I come to my problem. My react-native app is fetching data from `json-server` and storing it in `redux-store`. `redux-store` in turn stores it in `AsyncStorage` as I have printed the content of `storage` in my code. No problem till now.

But now I turn off my `json-server` and exit my app on my android device to test `redux-persist`( I don't recompile it, I just exit it). As I open it again, redux, instead of looking in `AsyncStorage`, it again tries to contact `json-server` to fetch the data( rather it should look into the `asyncstorage`). Now since the server is not running, the app cannot fetch data and writes an error message into the state( as I have configured it like that way). So, `AsyncStorage` again gets emptied and the application renders nothing. Now I present you the code of `configureStore.js`:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import { dishes } from './dishes';
import { comments } from './comments';
import { promotions } from './promotions';
import { leaders } from './leaders';
import { favorite } from './favorite.js';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { logger } from "redux-logger";
import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const config = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    debug: true
  }

export const ConfigureStore = () => {
    const store = createStore(
        persistCombineReducers(config,{
            dishes,
            comments,
            promotions,
            leaders,
            favorite
        }),
        applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
    );

    const persistor = persistStore(store)
    return {persistor, store};
}
```

Below is App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from './components/MainComponent';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConfigureStore } from './redux/configureStore';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react'
import  Loading  from './components/LoadingComponent';

const { persistor, store } = ConfigureStore();
//const store=ConfigureStore();


class App extends React.Component{
  
  render(){
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate 
          loading={<Loading />}
          persistor={persistor}>
          <Main /></PersistGate>
      </Provider>
  );
}
};

export default App;
```

One other strange thing that I must tell you is that out of 5 reducers, only comments and favorites are the two reducers whose data is being persisted even after app restart and I also have not made it any different from other 3.

Below is comments.js reducer:

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';

export const comments = (state = { errMess: null, comments:[]}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENTS:
      return {...state, errMess: null, comments: action.payload};

    case ActionTypes.COMMENTS_FAILED:
      return {...state, errMess: action.payload};

    case ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENT:
      {action.payload.id=state.comments.length;console.log("hello from reducer",action.payload);return {...state,comments: [...state.comments,action.payload]}}

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Below is dishes.js:

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';


export const dishes = (state = { isLoading: true,
                                 errMess: null,
                                 dishes:[]}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        
        case ActionTypes.ADD_DISHES:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: null, dishes: action.payload};

        case ActionTypes.DISHES_LOADING:
            return {...state, isLoading: true, errMess: null, dishes: []}

        case ActionTypes.DISHES_FAILED:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: action.payload};

        default:
          return state;
      }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a whitelist and blacklist.

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  blacklist: ['navigation'] // navigation will not be persisted
};
 
// WHITELIST
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['navigation'] // only navigation will be persisted
};
```

Try This Way :

```
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    whitelist: ["dishes, comments, promotions, leader, favorite"]
  }

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    dishes: dishes,
    comments: comments,
    promotions: promotions,
    leaders: leaders,
    favorite: favorite
});

const persistReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(persistReducer,  applyMiddleware(thunk));

let persistor = persistStore(store);

export {store, persistor};
```

Comment: i have aleady used it, it is not working as well. I don't understand why only comments and favorite are being persisted. Apart from these two, everything is lost when I restart app.

Comment: I wonder what will happen if my problem gets solved and when everything is working fine, the app again tries to contact server and when it will fetch nothing, it will write an error message to the state and it will get updated and the UI will vanish?? Will it happen??

Comment: I must assume that on API call success this action is called ActionTypes.ADD_DISHES, even if it returns 0 data. ActionTypes.DISHES_FAILED and this when there is a server error or a timeout.
Still need a whole code to analyze why this happens in your case.

Comment: Yes you are right. But my instructor used exact same code without any problem.

Comment: Wait. I am giving you the git repo.

Comment: https://github.com/tyagivipul629/ReactNativeProject

Comment: You will better understand what is happening in the app.

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: I have tried this as well. It doesn't seem to work, still only comments and favorite are being persisted

Comment: Try to downgrade it from 6 to 5.6.12. I guess there might be an issue in this version 6.

Comment: Try to downgrade more. Other then please confirm the version from the instructor code also.
I mostly do not use the latest version of redux-persist. Most of the projects I worked on installed with 5.6.12 or lower.

Comment: It is not working with any of the version. Very poor module.

Comment: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/1114#issuecomment-658365131

Debug might be issue

Answer (score 0):

- List item

After scratching my head for nearly a day, only one switch case in all reducers is causing problem. That case is `LOADING` case. I made my dishes.js reducer like this:

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';


export const dishes = (state = { isLoading: true,
                                 errMess: null,
                                 dishes:[]}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        
        case ActionTypes.ADD_DISHES:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: null, dishes: action.payload};

        
        case ActionTypes.DISHES_FAILED:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: action.payload};

        default:
          return state;
      }
};
```

I changed other reducers in the same way and everything started working like a charm!!